# program does not compile with newer version of g++

Tags: c++

I have the following source code. Which compiles fine in visual studios and g++ 3.4.6; but not with g++ 4.4.3 (on a newer ubuntu machine). The newer compiler requires that I explicitly include  to use atoi. I am just trying to figure out what might have changed to cause this behavior. Is it sstream header file previously included cstdlib and no longer does so. Or is it the compiler behavior that has changed.

```
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  char str1[]="123";
  int i = atoi(str1);

  printf ("value = %d",i);
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: what you showed is **not** c++. you should either move to normal c++ or stop deceiving yourself.

Comment: Relax. This is just an example. If you don't have anything useful to say related to my question stay quite.

Comment: @Mandeep Don't worry about such comments at all. Using non-objective parts of C++ is totally OK.

Comment: @Andrey: the word you're looking for is 'idiomatic'.  It's not idiomatic C++.  It is perfectly valid C++, however (give or take the header issues).

Comment: just check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245196/c-urban-myths the first answer. it is very good.

Comment: @Mandeep in comments i am free to tell anything i feel relevant, so please don't tell me when to be quite. what you showed is plain C, but yes, it is valid C++, but there is nothing c++ish in it.

Comment: @Andrey How is that related to this? Yes there are many differences between C and C++ creating various incompatibilities. This is a perfectly valid and correct C++ code (apart from the include).

Comment: @Andrey And I would guess that this invalid C code (valid C++) is still C `int main() { int x = 200, y = 100; (x=y)=10; return x; }` and not C++.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be i am not saying about validity, but more about style: `string` instead of `char[]`, `std::out` instead of `printf`. well, i can accept `atoi`, but still i prefer `stringstream`s.

Comment: @Andrey There is a huge difference between preferring some style and saying that a code isn't C++ (as you did in the first comment).

Comment: @Andrey - "nothing c++ish"?  what the heck is that. Would you only consider code using C++'s OO features to be c++ish or do I have to use templates. I work on a C++ project with heavy use of OO; but there is a large chunk of legacy code which is mainly written in "c style", so didn't have much of choice on what I can do there.

Comment: @Mandeep ok, my comment was too exaggerated. but i still think that you should not really call it c++. i am not saying that you do something wrong, it was just about naming.

Answer (score 10):

You also need to include `<cstdio>` for `printf()`.

Technically, if you include the headers of the form `<cname>` instead of `<name.h>`, you also need to qualify the names from the standard library using `std::`.  A lot of standard library implementations are relaxed when it comes to this, though, and also put the names into the global namespace.

It's implementation-dependent which headers are included by which other headers, so you should always be sure to include all the headers that you need and not assume that they will be included automatically.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using GCC 4.4.5 on Debian, and the headers have changed so you will not bring in the headers necessary. You need to `#include <cstdlib>` and `#include <cstdio>` to get `atoi` and `printf`, as the compiler complained about both being missing.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>


int main()
{
  char str1[]="123";
  int i = std::atoi(str1);

  std::printf ("value = %d",i);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well yes. That is common. You should always include ALL headers that you are directly using and not depend on the fact that those headers are already included.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler behavior is what would have changed... the `<sstream>` doesn't use `atoi`.

Arguably you should have always done `#include <cstdlib>`, and you'd gotten lucky with your previous compilers.

As James McNeillis points out, you should also `#include <cstdio>` in order to use the `printf` function.

Comment: I was leaning the other way because if I change the code so that <sstream> is not included the program does not compile with the older version of g++.

Comment: You should just always include the headers you're going to need, and as a programmer it's your responsibility to know what those are (or know how to look them up). So put another way, I'm saying you should include BOTH of those headers.

Comment: I agree. Actually I been tasked with updating to a newer version of g++; I am fixing it by including the appropriate headers, but I just found it odd that the other comipler's didn't mind this. So, I just wanted to figure out what the root cause was.